# Unable to pass null value in string.Format()

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have one ComboBox name as `cmbCity` which has dataSource as `DisplayMember` "CityName" (string type) and `ValueMember` "ValueID" (Number type).

Now for update `dataTable` I have query

```
string query = string.Format("Update TableName Set StringTypeColmName = '{0}' , NumberTypeColmName = {1}", 
                             "StringValue", 
                             !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbCity.Text) ? cmbCity.SelectedValue : DBNull.Value);`.
```

Its work fine if user select value form `cmbCity`, I get value by `cmbCity.SelectedValue` by if user dont select any value then I am trying to pass null value in database for that field but after formating string, I get value like

```
Update TableName Set StringTypeColmName = 'StringValue' , NumberTypeColmName = "
```

in this output string null value not present and finally while executing query I got exception `Syntax error in UPDATE statement.`. Any help how to add null value in output query. I am using MS-Accesss database and VS2010.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work, you should pass "null" string if the value is not present:

```
string.Format("Update TableName Set StringTypeColmName = '{0}' , NumberTypeColmName = {1}", 
"StringValue", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbCity.Text) ? cmbCity.SelectedValue.ToString() : "null");
```

Comment: And where in this query comparing happens exactly?

Comment: Yes its working thank you for your answer. I would mark this as answer after 5 min!

Comment: @AnkushMadankar nakki mark kara saheb , yachyawar anyay zalay, kami upvotes milalet.

Comment: @Navat Kay Ahe manunch me Upvote kela an answer mark pan kela..!

Answer (score 8):

You should probably (no, scratch that, *definitely*) not use string formatting for building parametrised SQL queries. Instead, use the appropriate classes, e.g.:

```
using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand("Update TableName Set StringTypeColmName = ?, NumberTypeColmName = ?", connection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("string", "StringValue");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("num", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbCity.Text) ? cmbCity.SelectedValue : DBNull.Value);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Since this uses the database driver to handle replacement of the parameters this is actually safe to do, even if a `ToString()` on a value would result in the empty string.

Comment: Apologies if this is all wrong, I'm still trying to figure out how to properly use parameters with `OleDbCommand`s. The general idea remains valid, though.

Comment: Yes, this also one way to update datatable but in case of number of colm datatable I like to use formatted string rather than passing parameters to query..! which will reduce code and increase code readability.. In this case `ToString()` works since I have already added `IsNullOrEmpty()` check for same.